# Configure flapdoodle embedded mongodb for transaction

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, transactions, flapdoodle-embed-mongo

I'm using "Flapdoodle Embedded MongoDB" for integartion test. It works fine.
After adding the transaction manager, I have the following error:

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: This MongoDB deployment does not support retryable writes. Please add retryWrites=false to your connection string.
```

Here is my application.properties file. I'm not using a connection string for tests. I only added the database version.

```
de.flapdoodle.mongodb.embedded.version=5.0.5
```

I tried to add  an implementation of AbstractMongoClientConfiguration. But, it didn't fix the issue.

```
@Configuration
public class EmbededMongoTransactionConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

@Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
private String database;

@Bean
MongoTransactionManager mongoTransactionManager(MongoDatabaseFactory dbFactory) {
    return new MongoTransactionManager(dbFactory);
}

@Bean
MongodArguments mongodArguments() {
    return MongodArguments.builder().replication(Storage.of(database, 10)).build();
}

@Override
protected String getDatabaseName() {
    return database;
}
}
```

I'm using the following dependencies (springboot 2.7.8):

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring27x</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Can you help with configuring flapdoodle mongoDb to work with a transaction?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring/blob/main/HowTo.md#transactions

Tough worked well on my local machine whereas failed in docker container. No info on this particular case so far

Comment: I've learned that transactions in mongodb are available when replica set is on https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/replication/#transactions https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions/ Thank's for link above it helped me to resolve my problem!